# If $ab+bc+ac=3abc$ then prove that $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\geq 2(a+b+c)−3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have this problem and I tried to do it but I did too much calculations and I feel like I'm using the wrong method.

Here's the problem :

> $a,b,c$ are all real and positive numbers. If $ab+bc+ac=3abc,$ then prove that $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \geq 2(a+b+c)-3$$

Comment: Titles should be used to help readers figure out if they can help you. This title is useless for that purpose.

Comment: What should I write instead ?

Comment: Also, what did you try -- what are these calculations you did and didn't allow you to conclude? (Note also that "really need it" is somewhat insulting, as a title: do you expect that every other question on the site is not needed, and sort of optional and useless to their posters?)

Comment: I'm sorry. But I tried so many calculations I can't write them all.

Comment: I think it should be $\geq$ not $>$, since if $a=b=c=1$, then $3=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a=2(a+b+c)-3=3$.

Comment: Zack, welcome to the community. We love to help and solve problems, to see how to best encourage others to help you in your struggles please see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice.

Comment: @Zack writing them all would be tedious, but it would help members of this site if you discussed at least one or two things you tried. Or what you think might be the key to figuring out this problem, but just can't quite figure out the missing step to complete it.

Comment: I tried to simplify. Didn't work then I tried to prove that a2b+b2c+c2a-2(a+b+c)−3 belongs to R+. but I couldn't.

Comment: And I also tried to prove that (a2b+b2c+c2a)/2(a+b+c)−3>1 but also I had problems with that.

Comment: And please be a little tolerant because I'm only 15 years old.

Comment: I guess this problem is from some math competition. Try to study methods of solving similar problems, for example http://db.math.ust.hk/notes_download/elementary/algebra/ae_A5c.pdf

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It seems that the only $a$, $b$ and $c$ where there is equality (and not strict inequality) is your example $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: Zack, we are tolerant. As you can see, we've been helping you a bit already. On your part, please be willing to familiarize yourself with the etiquette of the site, it will make you an informed member of our community and improve the responses you get.

Comment: Thank you. I promise I will.

Comment: Your inequality is obviously true after homogenization and full expanding. It's better firstly to use the following substitution: $a=\frac{1}{x}$, $b=\frac{1}{y}$ and $c=\frac{1}{z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

The constraint gives you $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=3$

Use that and three AM-GMs of form $a^2b+\dfrac1b\ge2a$ to conclude.

Comment: Could you please explain more on how to use the three AM-Gm of form a2b+1b≥2a to conclude ?

Comment: Cyclically permute the variables, so that you get three inequalities with the terms in desired LHS. Then just add them, you get your inequality.

Comment: Try it out, you can edit your question to show the workings, then let me know if you need further help.